# Is it possible to keep increasing the values in a list through a single loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

If I had the following list:
'new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
and I set a counter value to 0:
'counter = 0'
If I wanted to keep increasing the list values by 1/10th until the numbers have all increased by 1, could I do that in a single loop?

the code I have previously tried is this:

```
new = [1,2,3,4,5]
counter = 0
newLst = []
while counter <= 10:
   counter = counter + 1
   for i in new:
       i = i * 1.1
       newLst.append(i)
print(newLst)
```

The output I would want, would be:

```
[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
[1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2]
```

etc.. all the way to the end list value of:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Don't name lists list, it overrides a builtin name.

Comment: Until the numbers have doubled?  What is the wanted result? `[1,1.1,1.2, .... 9.9, 10.0]` ?

Comment: My wanted result is [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]

Comment: and those all the way up to [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want, more or less. It's a bit tricky dealing with the specific value `0.1` though, as it can't be reproduced precisely as a floating point number (you may get values like `0.30000000000000004` when you multiply it by 3 instead of the expected `0.3`). But you can either ignore those errors or compute the values differently (such as `3/10` instead of `0.1*3`).

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    newLst = []
    for j in range(1, 6):
        newLst.append(j + i / 10)
    print(newLst)
```

If you were using Python 2, you used to need to do `i / 10.0` (with a float literal) to ensure that the division gave a floating point result, rather than truncating to an integer. Python 3 does float division by default, and you can also get this behavior if you put `from __future__ import division` at the top of a file in Python 2.